# Ordering a NodaTime Nullable OffsetDateTime

Tags: c#, sorting, nullable, nodatime

I have a class Appointment that contains a nullable NodaTime.OffsetDateTime property. If I have a list of Appointments, how would I use Linq `OrderBy` to order this list with the null `StartDateTime` first then StartDateTime in descending order?

```cs
Class Appointment
{
    public OffsetDateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I tried doing this

```cs
var orderedAppointments = myAppointmentsList
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDateTime is null)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.StartDateTime, OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Local)
    .ToList();
```

but I get an error because the OffsetDateTime.Comparer cant handle null values.

I could do something like this

```cs
var orderedAppointments = myAppointmentsList
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDateTime ?? StartDateTime.MaxValue, OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Local)
    .ToList();
```

but `StartDateTime` doesn't have `MaxValue`.

What is the recommendation here, create my own `OffsetDateTime` max value, or is there a better way of doing this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the null values first? Then you could use:

```
var orderedAppointments = myAppointmentsList
    .OrderBy(x => x.StartDateTime.HasValue ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.StartDateTime.GetValueOrDefault(), OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Local)
    .ToList();
```